# Google Analytics - Google Organic traffic with backslash

Tags: google-analytics, infinite-scroll

We have recently rolled out an infinite scroll feature in the site that could be generating this issue but we are not sure why/what is causing this. Every page visit and event is reported correctly, but in some cases the page view is prefixed with "/", (e.g. "/https://www..."). It is only happening in Organic traffic from Google. Any ideas would be more than welcome. We included a canonical link in those pages that contains infinite scroll. As a check we did run a crawler and there are no links in the site like those so not sure how to find the error source.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have posted the question on webmasters as it makes more sense to have it there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! A `pageView` event was fired using absolute url instead of relative url. Changing it seems to have fixed the issue.